# How to pass a string to Angular 2 (click) function?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have a div element in my HTML like so

```
<div (click) = onPaginationClick()>next</div>
```

My question is : How to pass a string to the onPaginationlick() function ? when i try to pass it like this :

```
<div (click)=onPaginationClick("myString")>next</div>
```

I have a parse template error.

Enyone can help ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to wrap the whole expression in quotes if it itself contains quotes:

```
<div (click)="onPaginationClick('myString')">next</div>
```

Comment: @gunther, what if i need to evaluate a value in place of my string

Comment: @VinaySingh then omit the quotes. Not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use nested quotes:

```
<div (click)="onPaginationClick('helloworld')">next</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your **component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class AppComponent {
  ...
  onPaginationClick(value): void {
     ...
  }
}
```

In your **component.html**

```
<div (click)="onPaginationClick('helloworld')">next</div>
```